# Disappearing menus on MacOS Sonoma

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, macos-sonoma

We develop an Eclipse RCP Application, still using Eclipse 3 framework.

After updating our Mac to the new MacOS, Sonoma, the menus started behaving strangely when sub-menus are shown (see below): after a submenu is shown and then hid, through hovering, the parent menu is also hidden.

[image]

If we open our app on debug mode, from inside Eclipse (we're using Eclipse 2020-12), the menus behave correctly.

We believe this might hint that there's some ambient setting that our application "inherits" from its host, Eclipse itself, on debug time. We've seen it before when we had to add "-NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance True" to our debug configuration.

Does anyone have any idea if there's such a setting on Mac that might affect menus behavior?

Comment: You really should keep your underlying platform version more closely in sync with the macOS release. You'll note that the Target Environments for macOS are *very* limited for each release: https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?planurl=http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_29.xml#target_environments

Comment: I'm not seeing this with my e4 based RCPs or in Eclipse 2023-09 (which is just a large RCP mostly using the Eclipse 3 framework). The only Sonoma issues that I am aware of is splash screens displaying upside down and the app name sticking as "NewApplication"

Comment: Yeah, @greg-449, I see that too.  It's really strange.  Only on the exported product this behavior shows up.  I'm trying to discover what's different on the application when we run it from inside Eclipse, debugging.

Comment: When you run in debuging Eclipse invokes Java directly, when you run the built RCP you run the RCP executable which links to Java. This results in different versions of the macOS libraries being used which gives some variations on behaviour.

Comment: Precisely our thoughts.  Do you know if there's a way to check which libraries are being used, or their settings?

Comment: `otool -l /path/to/executable` lists lots of info, the `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` section is the macOS SDK version. For Eclipse I get 10.14, for Java 21 I get 11.0. I belive that is statically linked so not easy to change.

Comment: Hey, @greg-449, thank you very much for your tip on the difference between how Java is started (executable vs. debug).  This led us to the discovery that if we start our application directly with java (java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.jar) the problem is gone.  It seems, then, that the problem starts with the native launcher.  Unfortunately, as documented, "on MacOSX the launcher always load the vm in-process using the JNI invocation API", so it seems we'll need to switch to create our own starter, to start Java in a new process.  Again, thank you very much for the tip.